# Setting the size of navigation buttons in GridView footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with some custom images for navigation in the footer.
(First,Next, Previous and Last)
It does Work, but the images are shown in a very large size.
They are only 40 pixels high (the PNG's) but they are shown much larger, and it looks very stupid.

I cannot find any setting for Width and/or Height that seem to control the size of the images.

These are my settings so far:

```
<FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC"  ForeColor="Black" />
<PagerStyle   BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black"></PagerStyle>
<PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" 
     FirstPageImageUrl="/Images/Design/first.png"
     NextPageImageUrl="/Images/Design/next.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CssClass attribute in your PagerStyle.

```
<PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="pagestyle"></PagerStyle>
```

And CSS:

```
.pagestyle img{
     width:40px;
     height:50px;
}
```

I think, This should work but this is untested.

Comment: No, that doesn't Work, it is one of the many Things I have tried so far. I Wonder what I am doing wrong, because no one else seem to have hvad this issue. It is VS 2012 by the way.